SwiftUI Best ways to prevent onChange from executing until values have loaded
I'm trying to observe some state variables, of which are set/loaded when the entire view appears using .onAppear(). Problem is, this onChange is firing when the user loads the view without editing the @State variables due to my .onAppear updating the state variables after some synchronous/asynchronous task.
struct ExampleView: View{
    
    @State var ExampleVar: String = ""
    
    var body: some View{
        VStack{
            TextField("Example", text: $ExampleVar)
        }
        .onChange(of: ExampleVar){
            print("this will fire when the text field is updated within onAppear")
        }
        .onAppear(){
            ExampleVar = "test@test.com"
        }
    }
}

I have tried setting a flag to conditionally execute code in the onChange, however there seems to be some data race and the onChange is executed when the view loads sometimes. Surely there is a easier way to disregard the first onChange fire?

You could try adding .onSubmit {...} to the TextField instead of using .onChange.
Note that a simple flag in .onChange works well for me in my tests.

@workingdogsupportUkraine I'm not just using a TextField, I'm using other UI elements such as a Picker view.

Please add your code with the conditional flag to your question.

That's too late, in SwiftUI the state is set and then you describe the Views you want to show it with. i.e. don't wait for an empty UI to appear and then decide. Btw this is called view being a function of state.
To solve this you might need a State struct in a parent View and then you pass a binding to one of its properties into this View.
Requested example:
struct ExampleConfig {
    var exampleVar: String = ""
    var isShowing = false

    mutating func show(initialText: String) {
        exampleVar = initialText
        isShowing = true
    }
}

struct ContentView: View{
    
    @State var config = ExampleConfig()

    var body: some View {
        Button("Show") {
            config.show(initialText: "test@test.com")
        }
        if config.isShowing {
            ExampleView(exampleVar: $config.exampleVar)
        }
    }
}


Could you share an example of what you mean?

Sure I added it.
